# Matlab : Using each element of a column vector to go through a series of calculations (iterations?)

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, for-loop, iteration

`theta1 = theta(:,1);` //This is a column vector of data extracted from an `18x30` matrix theta1 is 18x1.

Then from here I need to go through each of the individual 18 elements one at a time with the following calculations:

```
nx =((cos(theta1(1))^2)/(1.5^2) + ((sin(theta1(1))^2)/(1.7^2)))^(-1/2);
```

Here I have selected the first element using "`theta1(1)`" but ideally I would like to somehow use a for loop so that this calculation can be done for all 18 values of 
"theta1" that I have and then produce another 18x1 matrix of "nx". I have tried using a for loop but I can't get it to work correctly.

Then after this I want to use each of the 18 elements of "nx" in another calculation to get another variable:

```
d = (2*pi*(nx-1.5)*0.000018)/0.000000555;
```

So, I am looking for some sort of general for loop or any other suitable method that would allow me to do this type of calculation where I use each element in an array and plug it into a formula and produce another array with the answer of the calcualation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate what's the problem with a for-loop?

Comment: Well I can't figure out how I would do a for loop which will do the calculation for "nx" for all the 18 values in my array "theta1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
nx =((cos(theta1(:)).^2)/(1.5^2) + ((sin(theta1(:)).^2)/(1.7^2))).^(-1/2);
d = (2*pi*(nx(:)-1.5)*0.000018)/0.000000555;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, and was so simple aswell; well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
theta = rand(18,30);
theta1 = theta(:,1);
nx =(cos(theta1.^2)/(1.5.^2) + (sin(theta1.^2)/(1.7^2)).^(-1/2))
d = (2*pi*(nx-1.5)*0.000018)/0.000000555
```

If you use a `.` before the `^` operator the vector will be square them element-wise (the same works with `.*`,`./`). Look up [arithmetic operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the .^ operator.